# Using External Data in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, bcs, sql-server, external-data

Hi i am new to SharePoint, i have been given a requirement and i am not able to find the right approach. 
We have a SharePoint portal which keeps track of employees details, very recently we have installed bio-metric machine in our office and that machine sends data to a .net application which uses sql server to store the data.
I need a way to fetch that data(bio-metric machine data stored in sql) and populate a list in SharePoint every time there is a change in data sent by biometric machine.
Please help me find the right approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As data stored into the SQL Database, then you have a choice to use BCS. To access external Data from SharePoint, you have to use the BCS.BCS enable you to create External Content Types and External Lists from SQL Server Database.

[Deploy a Business Connectivity Services on-premises solution in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219584.aspx)

[How to: Create external content types for SQL Server in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx)

Comment: Thank for your reply. That was my first thought too, but the problem is i have to add this data to existing list without making changes to its current content types, so is it possible to add the data from sql to existing list.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that may be worth exploring is to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). There's package on Codeplex that integrates SharePoint with SQL Server for data integration. See here for more details -

[Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx)